# Right click context menu does not appear in a particular network diagram

Tags: cytoscape

I have been constructing a network diagram for months and now all of a sudden when I right-click on the network diagram (node or background) I no longer get the context menu and cannot e.g. rename a node, or create a new node. I don't know how this happened. Right-clicking on edges produces a context menu,  but less options are available than normal. It doesn't otherwise produce an error. It seems to be the case for all networks within one network collection.

The context menus behave normally on other networks in a different network collection open in the same session.

Please help if you can suggest a fix or a way to produce more debugging information.
Thanks!
-Justin

Tried right-clicking on the network diagram (background, node), but no context menu is produced for networks within a particular network collection. Other network collections seem to behave normally.

Comment: HI Justin.  Two suggestions: (1) try saving and restoring the session.  If that doesn't work, then (2) try disabling any apps you might not be using.   If neither of those do the trick, perhaps you can tell us what edge context menu items you see.  That might give us more of a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: hi Scooter. Sorry for the late reply. l thought I would receive an email notice if someone responded, but apparently not. I've tried restoring it several times. I've also reinstalled cytoscape. I found a sort of work-around that works sometimes: I import a network from a database. When it imports the new network, it re-enables the context menus. However, even this solution seems to no longer work for me. At the moment it seems that context menus work for nodes and edges, but not for the background, so I can't e.g. add a node.  I just tried uninstalling all of the apps, and this worked for now.